# Scraping infinite scrolling website with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, infinite-scroll

I would like to scrap the content of this website that has scrolling:
http://stocktwits.com/symbol/AAPL?q=AAPL

I found this answer for a similar question in Stactoverflow:
[scrape websites with infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519074/scrape-websites-with-infinite-scrolling)

and here is the code copied from there:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import sys

import unittest, time, re

class Sel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://twitter.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
    def test_sel(self):
        driver = self.driver
        delay = 3
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/search?q=stckoverflow&src=typd")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
        for i in range(1,100):
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(4)
        html_source = driver.page_source
        data = html_source.encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Now instead of twitter I want to scrap Stocktwits website (the link is above).

I modified the above code to this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import sys

import unittest, time, re

class Sel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://stocktwits.com/symbol/AAPL?q=AAPL"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
    def test_sel(self):
        driver = self.driver
        delay = 3
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
        for i in range(1,100):
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(4)
        html_source = driver.page_source
        data = html_source.encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"All"}
```

I appreciate any help to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
```

You're expecting an element with link text `"All"` but none exists.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, so what should I have instead of `All`?

Comment: Well it depends what's actually on the page. Is there a link you want to click?

Comment: I want to scroll down.

Comment: Ok maybe it's an artifact from the code you copied? If you don't actually want to click any links then you can delete that line.

Comment: And it automatically scrolls down?

Comment: Well that line isn't related to the scrolling down. The code for the scrolling down is the loop with the `execute_script` in it following that line.

Comment: Thanks, so in that code it tries 100 times to scroll down?

Comment: Actually 99 times, but yes :p